# How to inject child dependency using byType autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have two child classes(PermanentEmployee and ContractEmployee) of Employee class.

I want spring to inject the dependencies under TextEditor1 by type . Along with this i want to inject the PermanentEmployee depndency under TextEditor1.

similarily want to inject the contractEmployee dependency under TextEditor2. Rest should be injected
automatically by type?

```
       <bean id="textEditor1" class="com.TextEditor"   autowire="byType">
           <property name="employee" ref="permanentEmployee" />
       </bean>

        <bean id="textEditor2" class="com.TextEditor"   autowire="byType">
           <property name="employee" ref="contractEmployee" />
       </bean>


        <bean id="permanentEmployee" class="com.PermanentEmployee" >
       </bean>

        <bean id="contractEmployee" class="com.ContractEmployee">
       </bean>
```

But i get the error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:  saying two match are found` ?

**Update :-**  i also tried below but it didn't work either

```
       <bean id="textEditor1" class="com.TextEditor"   autowire="byType">
         <qualifier type="permanentEmployee"/>
       </bean>
```

Comment: `autowire="byType"` is redundant， try remove it

Comment: If i remove autowire="byType" spring will inject only employee dependency but not others. As i said in my post i want both

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because those two `com.PermanentEmployee` and `com.ContractEmployee` are implementing another interface like `com.Employee`?

That way, Spring will recognize those same type and can't choose which bean Spring have to auto-wire into the bean.

So you might need to add those `byName`, not `byType` in this case.

If you change those injection with `@Autowired` annotation or `@Resource` annotation, you can use `@Qualifier`( for Autowired ) or name property of Resource annotation to specify bean name.

Comment: I agree i can do it with @Qualifier but i wanna do it with declarative way. I also agree i can do it with byName.But i am mainly interested if i can do it with byType or not ?

Comment: You can't with current situation as far as I'm aware of. Maybe you can if you stop implementing common interface.